# Custom Keyboard in iOS 9 crashes after adding an UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, custom-keyboard

My custom keyboard runs smooth and nice. Now, I wanna add an `UICollectionView`. I added it in the control to my view in the Interface Builder and the data source and delegate protocol to my view controller which is the File's owner of the related xib file and linked it to the control.

If I deploy and run the app, I will always get the error message:

> "plugin xxx-Keyboard interrupted"

If i remove the collection view, I'm able to run the keyboard without any problems.

This is how I connect the keyboard extension view controller to the xib file:

```
    let nib     = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
    let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
    view        = objects[0] as! UIView
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lesson learned today:

- You cannot debug an extensions like the "main" app

  - You have to attach the debugger by hand to the process
- If something crashes inside the extension, there is only the "interrupted label"
- If everything works properly, the view / custom keyboard will load